# Nginx - Password Protect Not Working

Tags: nginx

I have followed instructions and still I cant password protect my site. This is what my app-nginx.config looks like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  Server_Test;
    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  /usr/local/nginx/conf/htpasswd;

...

}
```

Where am I going wrong? I copied and pasted this right from a tutorial site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just made my nginx server to work, and even configured it to protect my root folder access. I'd like to share my findings with you and on the way also give a good and working answer to the question in this page.

As a new user to nginx (Version 1.10.0 - Ubuntu).
The first problem I've got was to know the file locations, so here are the critical locations:

**Know your locations:**

Main folder location:  `/etc/nginx`

Default site location: `/var/www/` or even `/ver/www/html/` (inside the `html` folder will be the **index.html** file - hope you know what to do from there.)

**Configuration files:**

Main configuration file: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Current site **server** conf: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` (upon first installation there is a single file there that is called `default`, and you'll need to use `sudo` to be able to change it (for example:
`sudo vi default`)

**Add password:**

So, now that e know the players (for a static out-of-the-box site anyway) let's put some files in the 'html' folder and let's add password protection to it.

To setup a password we need to do 2 things:

1. create a passwords file (with as many users as we want, but I'll settle with 1).
2. Configure the current server ('default') to restrict this page and use the file in 1 to enable the password protection.

**1. Let's create a password:**

The line I'd like to use for this is:
`sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd john` (you'll get a prompt to enter and re-enter the password) of you can do it in a single line here:
`sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd john [your password]`

I'll explain each part of the command:

- `sudo htpasswd` - do it using higher permission.
- `-c`  - for: create file (to add another user to an existing user skip this argument)
- `/etc/nginx/.htpasswd` - the name of the file created
  ('.htpsswd' in the folder /etc/nginx)
- `john` is the name of the user (to enter in the prompted 'user' field)
- `password` is the needed password for this specific user name. (when prompted..)

Usually the `htpasswd` command won't work for you, so you'll have to install it's package:

Use: `sudo apt-get install apache2-utils` (if it fails try using `sudo apt-get update` and try again)

**2. Let's configure the server to use this file for authentication**

Let's use this line to edit the current (default) server conf file:

`sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` (You don't have to use 'vi' but I like it..)

The file looks like this after removing most of the comments (#)

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

We'll need to add two lines inside the block the location ('/' points to the root folder of the site) so it'll look like this:

```
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
     }
```

I'll explain these new lines:

- `auth_basic "Restricted Content";` - defines the type of access management
- `auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;` - defines the file we've created (/etc/nginx/.htppasswd) as the passwords file for this authentication.

Let's restart the service and enjoy a password protected site:

`sudo service nginx restart`

*Voila* - enjoy...

Here are some more great tutorials for this:

[Very good explanation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[Another goo tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: Not "Viola" but "Voilà" ;)

Comment: Also, the `auth_basic` directive does not define the type of access management, but just the title that will be used to display the password box to the user.

Comment: It does. Read the docs. It defines the title but also enables because off means disable

Comment: I truly appreciate this clear explanation. As someone who basically relearns this stuff every few years when I reactivate my sandbox, I'll spend hours trying to figure out how I just messed everything up and will even reprovision my Linode and start over. (BTW, 'viola' is often used ironically on the internet by people who know it's really voila, like 'rouge' for 'rogue' in gaming.)

Answer (score 19):

Make sure Nginx can access the password file. Paths for the auth_basic_user_file are relative to the directory of `nginx.conf`. So if your `nginx.conf` is located in `/usr/local/nginx` you can change your directive to:

```
auth_basic_user_file  conf/htpasswd;
```

and the file must be readable.

> This file should be readable by workers, running from unprivileged
>   user. E. g. when nginx run from www you can set permissions as:
>
> ```
> chown root:nobody htpasswd_file
> chmod 640 htpasswd_file
> ```

-- from http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule